# X.509 Certification for Android

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle, x509

Just a little background on my project:

I'm implementing an SMS encryption program using ECDH for Android (BouncyCastle) and I need to send my public keys over SMS. Functionality wise, all is up and working but I'm a little skeptical about the X.509 code I've implemented.

On the sender side:

```
        byte[] pubEnc = aKeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
        X509EncodedKeySpec  pubX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubEnc);
```

pubX509 is then encoded into Base64 and sent via SMS

On the receiver side:

```
        KeyFactory          keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
        X509EncodedKeySpec  pubX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(SharedS);
        ECPublicKey         pubKey = (ECPublicKey)keyFac.generatePublic(pubX509);
```

The received value is Base64 decoded into SharedS which is cast into a new pubX509

As I've mentioned, implementation wise, this code seems to be working fine, however I'd like to find out if I am implementing the X509 properly.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it is working, then what are you asking about?

Comment: Would like to know if this is the correct method of implementing X509. I did a little reading on X509 and it was mentioned that there was a need for a CA. Is this autogenerated by the device since I didn't specify anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that Sun (now Oracle) called this an X509EncodedKeySpec is simply because the public key is encoded using a format that was specified in the much larger X.509 certificate standard. For the internet, a proper implementation of X.509 certificates is specified in [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). As you can see, this RFC is over 140 pages in length. In the whole document, these 3 lines describe how to represent a public key:

```
   SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
        subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

And this is format that is produced by the Java class `X509EncodedKeySpec`. You can ignore all the rest of the X509 standard, you don't have to use certificates.